# Filtering through an array to match the text (jQuery / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, foreach

I have an unordered list called `$myList`. Every time a string (`$entry`) is entered into an input, I want to run through the list to see if that string is already in the list. If it is, I want to remove the list item that contains the matching string. Either way, the new string gets added and becomes a new list item.

Here's the most recent thing I tried:

```
$myList.text().filter($entry).remove();


$myList.append($entry);
```

It doesn't like that I'm doing `.text().filter()`, but none of the other things I've tried have worked either.

What's a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is `$myList`? `li` or `ul`?

Comment: for loop ie. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: It's a ul ........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filter` method should act on the list items, not on the `text()` value, since it is one of the list items you might need to remove. The `filter` method needs a *function* as argument. That function should determine whether or not the `text()` value of the iterated item is the entry text. Then the `remove` will work:

```
$('li', $myList).filter(function () { 
    return $(this).text() == entry;
}).remove();
```

```js
$('button').click(function () {
    var entry = $('input').val();
    var $myList = $('ul');
    $('li', $myList).filter(function () { 
        return $(this).text() == entry;
    }).remove();
    $('<li>').text(entry).appendTo($myList); // add item at end of list
    $('input').val(''); // clear input
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input><button>Add</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myList.find("li").filter(function() { // for each list item
    return $(this).text() === $entry;  // pick those who have the text equal to $entry
}).remove();                           // remove them

$("<li></li>").text($entry)            // create a new list item
              .appendTo($myList);      // add it to $myList
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `.each` function; it iterates through all the items inside the selector. I didn't use `.filter`, because I though `.each` would provide a more intuitive programming experience, as you both want to check if something exists and remove it if it does and append that same item to another list.

```js
$myList = $("#myList");
$entry = $("#entry");
$newList = $("#newList");

$entry.on('input', function () {
  entryText = $entry.val();
  $myList.find("li").each(function () {
    if ($(this).html() == entryText) {
      $("<li>")
        .append($(this).html())
        .appendTo($newList);
      $(this).remove();
    }
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Let's filter some tags<br />

<ul id="myList">
 <li>css</li>
 <li>js</li>
 <li>so</li>
 <li>sass</li>
 <li>haml</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" id="entry" />

<ul id="newList">
</ul>
```